# WP ForLoop to compare meta information of posts to determine what post to display

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, loop

The short of what I am trying to do here is: I want to display only one post based on a date stored in a custom field. I only want to display the post if it meets two conditions
1: The date needs to have not happened yet Ie must be larger than the current date
2: The date of the post to displayed has to be the closest to the current date out of all possible posts. Ie it's the next date to occur.

My problem is I can't figure out where to start when it comes to comparing one post to another then displaying only the appropriate one using the WordPress loop.
I think I would need to use a for loop to go over each post and do my comparing then run a new query to display my one post.

TLDR;
Can I use a forloop to go over a WP_Query? How can I access the post information in it?

Here is my Brainstoming code

```
<?php
  $current_date = strtotime(date( 'F j, g:i a' ));
  $soonest_date = 0;
  $post_to_display = 0;
  $posts = new WP_query($args); //will this work? Can I run a for loop over this?

  //loop through all posts (imagining the posts are stored in a $posts array)
  foreach( $posts as $post ) :
    $post_date = srttotime(get_field('date')); //Does this need to be $post['date']? or something like that?
    //Check if $soonest_date is set, if not then set it as the current post's date
    if(! $soonest_date){
       $soonest_date = $post_date;
    }

    //Check to see if the current post's date is larger than todays date and is less then the current soonest date
    if($current_date < $post_date < $soonest_date ){
        //if it is then this is the new soonest date and would be the one to be displayd if no smaller is found
        $soonest_date = $post_date;
        $post_to_display = the_ID(); // Again I think this might need to be something like $post['ID']?
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance! I tried to make this as clear as I could but i'm pretty confused :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_key' => '<ACF FIELD KEY HERE>',
    'meta_value'   => date( "Ymd" ),
    'meta_compare' => '>',
    'meta_query'  => array(
        'key' => '<ACF FIELD KEY HERE>',
        'value'  => date( "Ymd" ),
        'compare' => '>'
    ),
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value_datetime',
    'order'  => 'ASC',
);
$queryPosts = new WP_query($args);
if($queryPosts->have_posts) {
    while($queryPosts->have_posts) {
        $queryPosts->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves my problem in ensuring the one post to be displayed is the soonest, but I don't see how I can utilize this to ensure the date of the post to be displayed has not already happened. Compare in meta_query only allows me to select the operator to compare the meta of each post. I also need to compare the meta of each post with $current_date.

Comment: The meta_value is set to today `'meta_value'   => date( "Ymd" ),`

Comment: Okay so does seem on the right track however it does not function. My custom field has the date stored in a string like this: "2019-10-18 19:30:00" . date( 'F j, g:i a' ) will give me the same format, but I cannot compare two strings. I need to run strtotime() on both to get a unix timestamp and compare that, like in my code above. Can I run a function on a post's meta value before it's compared?

Comment: `'meta_value' => date( "Y-m-d g:i:s" )` should work.